# Is any weapon worshiped besides Sudarsana Chakra?

Tags: worship, sudarsana

I know that Sri Vaishnavas worship Sudarshana Chakra, giving it the status of an azhwar.  Does any other sect do so ?

Comment: Why don't you use the proper word Sri Vaishnavas? Ramanujiyas is not the correct word.

Comment: In North India during navratris, goddess is worshipped through making a trishul from sindoor on a wall.

Answer (score 1):

In south India, Vel (the weapon of Karthikeya) and trishul are installed in some Karthikeya and Shakti temples (near the respective vahanas) and are worshiped but not as a god/Alzhwar like Sudarshana. Sudarshana is also called Ayudhapurusha and sannidhis for him can be found in Vishnu temples like Varadaraja temple in Kanchi and in Srirangam.